# V2 = V1 or V2 = 0?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, homework

So, there is this question in my homework.

[image: This is the circuit.]

The node V1 is the one that connects straight to the ground, the node V2 is the one that connects to the 4k ohm resistor, 3k ohm resistor, and 2 mA current source.

We all know that V1 = V2. In this circuit, from what I see V1 is 12 volt (or is it 12-x/4000 + 2*10^-3 = 0, with the x as V1?). But, for V2, the node ends at the ground, which has the voltage value of zero (0).

Is the V2 value 0? or it is still the same as the V1? This is important because if I'm trying to determine V0, there will be KCL that involves the node above the ground.

Comment: "We all know that V1 = V2" - how do 'we' know this?

Answer (score 5):

1. You realize that you have a virtual short between In- and In+
2. You now know that In- is 0V
3. Therefore, you have 12V across the 4k resistor
4. Now you calculate the current in the 4k resistor.
5. Assuming that you have infinite input impedance in the OpAmp, you add the 2mA to the current of the 4k resistor and see that it flows into the 3k resistor
6. Knowing the current in the 3k resistor, you can calculate the voltage drop across it (because the left terminal is at zero volt)
7. Now you know Vout.
8. With Vout, you can calculate the current in the 6k resistor.
9. Use KCL to calculate iout

Answer (score -3):

The correct voltages are :V-=V+=0V

Because the inverting terminal of the opamp is connect to its output so we have a virtual ground

Comment: Do you know why?

Comment: Because the inverting terminal of the opamp is connect to its output so we have a virtual ground.